# Python find text in file between quotation marks

Tags: python

I'm trying to capture the text within quotation marks and set them as variables for me to change them at a later stage. I know how to do this in bash shell, but I'm at a loss how to do this in Python.

I've started with this, but I was hoping someone can point me where my mistakes are.

```
import re
input = open(filename, 'r')
quotes = re.findall(r'"[^"]*"', input.read(), re.U)
print quotes
```

Sadly though, this outputs:

```
['"test1"', '"test2"']
```

while I'm looking for:

```
value1 = test1
value2 = test2
```

In Bash I used this (but I obviously cant use it this way!):

```
i=0
regex='"([^"]*)"'
while read line
do
    if [[ $line =~ $regex ]]; then
        printf -v "text$i" '%s' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        i=$((i + 1))
    fi
done < filename

echo "value1: $text0"
echo "value2: $text1"
```

Comment: If it is the way it is printed that is a problem, you could print it like this: `print('\n'.join(("value"+str(quotes.index(i)+1) + " = " + i.strip('"') for i in quotes)))`

Answer (score 2):

Use a non-capturing group `(?:...)`, like this:

```
In [18]: re.findall('(?:")([^"]*)(?:")', '''hello "foo" "bar" haha''')
Out[18]: ['foo', 'bar']
```

Or use non-consuming groups `(?<=...)` etc:

```
In [14]: re.findall('(?<=")[^"]*(?=")', '''hello "foo" "bar" haha''')
Out[14]: ['foo', ' ', 'bar']
```

The latter has a side-effect of also selecting `" "` between `"foo"` and `"bar"`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is regex matching between two strings (`"` `"`).
Use the following:

```
vars = re.findall('"(.*?)"', text)
```

Answer (score 0):

the regex you're using in python isn't the same in bash.it should work with "([^"]*)". i tried..

```
import re
input = open(filename, 'r')
quotes = re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"', input.read(), re.U)
for value in quotes :
    print value
```

Comment: This helps towards a long way. Is there a way to catogorize them? First string is saved as value1 and second one as value2?

Comment: The best would still to keep every value in a list. then you could access the value you need by index
value1 = quotes[0]
value2 = quotes[1]

Comment: Ugh, indeed `"([^"]*)"` is the way to go, even simpler than my crud!