# Deleting part of a string in nested list python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, split, nested

I am trying to keep only a particular part of a string within my nested list.  My code is as follows:

```
answers = [
    ['person1', ' 2 1": ["answer 1"], "', ' 3 1": ["answer 0"], "', ...]
    ['person2', ' 2 1": ["answer 3"], "', ' 3 1": ["answer 1"], "', ...]]
```

I want to delete parts of the string so that the only piece that remains are:

```
answers = [
    ['person1', 'answer 1', 'answer 0', ...]
    ['person 2', 'answer 3', 'answer 1', ...]]
```

Comment: where `answers` object comes from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python find text in file between quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34155110/python-find-text-in-file-between-quotation-marks)

Comment: @AzatIbrakov answers comes from imported json data

Comment: Yeah, what did you do to get your list in this format? Maybe using something like `json.loads` would be helpful at an earlier step.

Comment: please give us example of original source so we can see if it can be done without manual string parsing

Comment: Due to the nature of the data, I am unable to give out the source.  However, it does need to be manually parsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works:

```
answers = [
           ['person1', ' 2 1": ["answer 1"], "', ' 3 1": ["answer 0"], "'],
           ['person2', ' 2 1": ["answer 3"], "', ' 3 1": ["answer 1"], "']]

result = []
for person_ans in answers:
    list = []
    for val in person_ans:
        if "[" in val:
            temp = val.split("[")
            output = temp[1].split("]")[0]
            list.append(output)
        else:
            list.append(val)
    result.append(list)
print result
```

Output:

```
[['person1', '"answer 1"', '"answer 0"'], ['person2', '"answer 3"', '"answer 1"']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
answers = [
    ['person1', ' 2 1": ["answer 1"], "', ' 3 1": ["answer 0"], "',],
    ['person2', ' 2 1": ["answer 3"], "', ' 3 1": ["answer 1"], "',]
]
```

You can use regexes to parse each string for the desired pattern `p`:

```
import re


p = re.compile(r'(?!.*\[)(\w+\s*\d)')
new_answers = []
for lst in answers:
    new_answers.append([re.search(p, s).groups(0)[0] for s in lst])
new_answers
# [['person1', 'answer 1', 'answer 0'], ['person2', 'answer 3', 'answer 1']]
```

This particular [pattern](http://pythex.org/?regex=(%3F!.*%5C%5B)(%5Cw%2B%5Cs*%5Cd)&test_string=%27%202%201%22%3A%20%5B%22answer%20108%22%5D%2C%20%22%27%0A&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) ignores characters behind the first bracket "[" and finds letters with zero or more spaces and digits.